# Cannot run docker-compose.yml in my Spring Boot Microservice Example (Failed to execute goal on project report)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem about running my **docker-compose.yml** in my **Spring Boot Microservice** example.

I got this error when the program tries to build **report service**.

```
Failed to execute goal on project report: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.springbootmicroservices:report:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact co
m.springbootmicroservices:advertisement:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

In my example, I added advertisement module as a dependency into report service because advertisementDTO from advertisement service cannot convert to advertisementDTO from report service. All these two dto are the same but I got this error. That's why I added it into report service.

Here is the link : [Pom.xml of report service](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/report-service/pom.xml)

I think it causes this issue in docker but I have no idea about how to fix it?

Here is my docker-compose.yml file : [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Here is the screenshot : [Image](https://ibb.co/1vN0NqJ)

1st Edited the post

```
ERROR: for userservice  Container "1b75c83ff656" is unhealthy.
ERROR: for reportservice  Container "1b75c83ff656" is unhealthy.
ERROR: for advertisementservice  Container "1b75c83ff656" is unhealthy.
```

I revised some codes in my repository.

I cannot fix the issue.

I updated my repository

Comment: Can you run a report-service container from the image that you build?

Comment: @Goffity I editted my post. Is it possible to look through it ?